# Reading a specific contact from its ID on android database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contacts

I need to set the cursor to a specific contact that i have its id

```
   Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,null, null, null);
```

I have that code for all the database, how can I optimize it?
I need the cursor to return the name and the default number of the contact

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need two cursors. One for name & id and another one for phone number.

```
 Cursor c = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

 if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    fullName  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("display_name_alt"));
    id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex
                   (ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
        //phone number

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                              null,
                              Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,
                              null, 
                              null);

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
               String number_type = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex
                              (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
               if(number_type.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    number1 = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex
                              (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
               if(number_type.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
                    number2 = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex
                              (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }

        phones.close();
    }
 }
 c.close();
```